# Header: location not working

Tags: php

I already searched for an answer here, but none of them could help me fix my problem.

I have a form with the following HTML code at the beginning:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" id="registration_form">
```

Standard form, whenever there is an error, the user will be redirected back to to registration form. Everytime, he is on that page, the following PHP code will be executed:

```
<?php
$fnameErr = $lnameErr = $emailErr = $pwErr = $pw_confErr = "";
$fname = $lname = $email = $pw = $pw_conf = "";

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
 if (empty($_POST["fname"])) {
    $fnameErr = "(Please submit first name)";
  } 
  else {
    $fname = test_input($_POST["fname"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
    $lnameErr = "(Please submit last name)";
  } 
  else {
    $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $emailErr = "(Please submit email address)";
  } 
  else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $emailErr = "(Email address is not valid)"; 
    }
  }

  include ("script/registration_email_compare.php");

  if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {
    $pwErr = "(Please submit password)";
  } 
  else {
    $pw = test_input($_POST["pw"]);
    $pwHash = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["pw_conf"])) {
    $pw_confErr = "(Please confirm password)";
  } 
  else {
    $pw_conf = test_input($_POST["pw_conf"]);
  }

  if ($_POST["pw"] !== $_POST["pw_conf"]) {
    $pwErr = "(Please confirm password)";
    $pw_confErr = "";
  } 

  if (empty($fnameErr) && empty($lnameErr) && empty($emailErr) && empty($pwErr) && empty($pw_confErr))
  {
    ob_start();
    include ("script/registration_db_add.php"); 
    include ("script/registration_send_mail.php");
    header("Location: registration_success.php");
    exit;
  }
}
?>
```

My problem now is that the user is added to my database, but he is not redirected to registration_success, but instead is redirected back to registration.php, where an empty page is returned.

I have no idea how to fix that error and couldn't find any suitable solutions, so I'm happy for any help.

Another extra info: my script is working on localhost, but not after I published it, that's pretty weird actually.

Comment: I would assume your location is already case-sensitive. How about trying an absolute URI instead of what you're currently doing, which is a relative?

Comment: Do any `registration_email_compare`, `registration_db_add`, or `registration_send_mail` contain any output content such as an echo or HTML content? I don't believe you can drop headers after content has already been injected into the response.

Comment: try putting the header("Location") after the exit;

Comment: What have you done to debug this? Are you confident that final if statement is evaluating the way you think it is? What is ob_start() doing for you?

Comment: @ZhiKai that's also not working

Comment: @forrestmid there aren't any echoes. The weird thing is, that it's working on localhost, but not on my public webhosting service

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yes, I'm sure that everything works how it is supposed to work. The weird thing is, that it's working on localhost, but not on my public webhosting service

I tried ob_start(), because I read somewhere, that it could be helpful, should I change the position of ob_start maybe?

Comment: Can you enable errors and see if it gives you any warnings or notices on the public server?